# What are some good algorithms to generate a dynamic heightmap?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, theory, heightmap

I want to research some algorithms for dynamic heightmap generation but I'm not familiar with any. Getting even more dynamic. Whats some theory on how multi-dimensional heightmaps work? i.e. Caves and overhangs. Should I use multiple heightmap images or complex algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple 2D heightmaps the [Diamond-square algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) produces reasonable results, and is fast. There are [a few things](http://oddlabs.com/download/terrain_generation.pdf) you can apply over the top of that to make it look more realistic, such as simple erosion, while still being very fast.

For more interesting features... if you want fast results, I'd stick with a 2D heightmap and then add secondary feature entities (i.e. boulders and holes), rather than try to generate a true 3D environment; but of course whether that comes close to being enough depends entirely on what you want to achieve.